# Helm not upgrading app to new version from my repo, even on recreating deployment

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I've created deployment with Helm

```
takayoshi@minikube:~$ sudo helm list
NAME                    NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART           APP VERSION
todo-app-1593610885     default         13              2020-07-01 13:56:28.395561055 +0000 UTC deployed        todo-app-1.0.0  1.0
```

As you can see my app has **version 1.0** and chart is **todo-app-1.0.0**
I upgraded my chart in repository and helm search give me result

```
takayoshi@minikube:~$ sudo helm search repo todo-app
NAME            CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
my/todo-app     1.1.0           1.1
```

After upgrade it gives me same version

```
takayoshi@minikube:~$ sudo helm upgrade todo-app-1593610885 todo-app
Release "todo-app-1593610885" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
NAME: todo-app-1593610885
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Jul  1 14:06:14 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 14
TEST SUITE: None
takayoshi@minikube:~$ sudo helm list
NAME                    NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART           APP VERSION
todo-app-1593610885     default         14              2020-07-01 14:06:14.103577369 +0000 UTC deployed        todo-app-1.0.0  1.0
```

Moreover if I delete and recreate mydeployment helm create with 1.0 version

```
takayoshi@minikube:~$ sudo helm uninstall todo-app-1593610885
release "todo-app-1593610885" uninstalled
takayoshi@minikube:~$ sudo helm install todo-app --generate-name
NAME: todo-app-1593612528
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Jul  1 14:08:49 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
takayoshi@minikube:~$ sudo helm list
NAME                    NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART           APP VERSION
todo-app-1593612528     default         1               2020-07-01 14:08:49.721404647 +0000 UTC deployed        todo-app-1.0.0  1.0
```

How can I upgrade my app?

My repo is https://krllevchenko.github.io/helm/index.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
entries:
  todo-app:
  - apiVersion: v2
    appVersion: "1.1"
    created: "2020-07-01T16:27:45.9002382+03:00"
    digest: fc66ebe7b404abd2b0f6054afce68aa0ee6c6789188778eeb6e71a665e9ecf64
    name: todo-app
    type: application
    urls:
    - https://krllevchenko.github.io/helm/todo-app-1.1.0.tgz
    version: 1.1.0
  - apiVersion: v2
    appVersion: "1.0"
    created: "2020-07-01T16:27:45.899239+03:00"
    digest: 59e61c0009df31d4c37ab95dc027d910f176d0ce723d4ff3bab9ba854f4fa7af
    name: todo-app
    type: application
    urls:
    - https://krllevchenko.github.io/helm/todo-app-1.0.1.tgz
    version: 1.0.1
  - apiVersion: v2
    appVersion: "1.0"
    created: "2020-07-01T16:27:45.8982364+03:00"
    digest: 6daa536f5957584b7f40f7150f80e4b57ddc739e3016e21d2f14f9ca406ce4c9
    name: todo-app
    type: application
    urls:
    - https://krllevchenko.github.io/helm/todo-app-1.0.0.tgz
    version: 1.0.0
generated: "2020-07-01T16:27:45.8962467+03:00"
```

Comment: looks like 1.1.0 chart is not the latest one, thy running `helm repo update` or using exact version `helm upgrade --version 1.1.0`

Comment: @edbighead not working. Same version again

Answer (score -1):

Since you are saving the chart of todo-app in a remote repository, I would suggest you have a local chart file, something like:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: my-local-chart
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: 1

dependencies:
- name: todo-app
  version: "1.1.0"
  repository: "https://krllevchenko.github.io/helm"
```

Then do a helm dependency update:

```
helm dependency update .
```

And then do a helm upgrade:

```
helm upgrade --install my-release .
```

Comment: Even though this thread is quite old, I have just come across the same problem. I am downvoting this since it is not only a workaround, but also a non feasable workaround. Helm is supposed to be used as a package manager. The OP stated it does not work in the expected way, and you basically suggested cumbersome/non scalable extra scripting which does not solve the original issue.